# How trace configure soap tracing at runtime in dll

Tags: c#, soap, trace

I try turn on soap tracing in my dll.
My app.conifig file includes:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true"/>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.Net" maxdatasize="10240">
        <listeners>
          <add name="TraceFile"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.Net.Sockets" maxdatasize="10240">
        <listeners>
          <add name="TraceFile"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="TraceFile" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
        initializeData="trace.log"/>
    </sharedListeners>
    <switches>
      <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose"/>
      <add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="Verbose"/>
    </switches>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

When I run dll in VisualStudio tracing works fine, but when I run dll from console it does not work. It seems like dll do not read app.config.
How can I turn on tracing from code or tuning it from external config file?

Comment: How do you run a ".dll"?

Answer (score 1):

You have configured it to work in dll. You can change it for console by adding a console listener as below:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true"/>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.Net" maxdatasize="10240">
        <listeners>
          <add name="TraceFile"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.Net.Sockets" maxdatasize="10240">
        <listeners>
          <add name="TraceFile"/>
          <add name="consoleListener" type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="TraceFile" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
        initializeData="trace.log"/>
    </sharedListeners>
    <switches>
      <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose"/>
      <add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="Verbose"/>
    </switches>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Notice the `consolelistener` that I have added. This will enable the code to write trace on console.

The sample configuration that worked for me is as below:

```
<configuration>
    <system.diagnostics>
        <trace autoflush="true">
            <listeners>
                <add name="logListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="cat.log" />
                <add name="consoleListener" type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener"/>
            </listeners>
        </trace>
    </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Your answer means, that trace should be written not only to file but to console as well. But in my question another situation: I run dll from console and I want see my trace in file.

Comment: @Balconsky Works perfectly at my end. May be the `<source>`section is messing up ..